# Is this the right way to implement a Iterator of Rc in Rust?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm implementing a tree that can share its nodes.

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
enum Tree<T> {
    Leaf(T),
    Node(Vec<Arc<Tree<T>>>),
}

impl<T> Tree<T> {
    fn children<'a>(self: &'a Arc<Self>) -> impl Iterator<Item = Arc<Tree<T>>> + 'a {
        match **self {
            Tree::Leaf(_) => panic!(),
            Tree::Node(ref children) => children.iter().cloned(),
        }
    }
}
```

This program passed the lifetime check, but I'm confused why do I need to write lifetime specifier explicitly.

```rust
impl<T> Tree<T> {
    fn children(self: &Arc<Self>) -> impl Iterator<Item = Arc<Tree<T>>> + '_
                                                                       // ~~ Is this `'a`?
    {
    // 'a
        match **self {
            Tree::Leaf(_) => panic!(),
            Tree::Node(ref children) =>
                //     ~~~~~~~~~~~~ Is this `&'a Vec<Arc<Tree<T>>>`?
                children.iter()
                    //   ~~~~~~ Is this `Cloned<std::slice::Iter<'a, Arc<Tree<T>>>>`?
                    .cloned(),
        }
    }
}
```

And I get this error:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src\main.rs:10:75
   |
10 |     fn children(self: &Arc<Self>) -> impl Iterator<Item = Arc<Tree<T>>> + '_
   |                                                                           ^^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
   = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from
```

Comment: Having a leaf panic rather than just return an empty iterator seems harsh. It's also really strange to have an argument `self` that is not the ordinary kind, as in `fn children(self)`. The `Arc` wrapper should have no bearing.

Comment: @tadman The tree I'm actually implementing is a bit more complex (like a functional zipper), I need this `Arc` to generate a reference count pointer to the parent node `Arc::clone(self)`. The code I posted here is just an example to demonstrate my question about lifetime.

Comment: I've found that instead of trying to think in terms of functions that operate on `Arc<X>` that often you should really write an `X` which has an internal `Arc<Y>` where `Y` represents the internals. That way `X` is cheap to clone, but you can also avoid this "weird `self` argument" issue. Like you could even have `struct Tree(Arc<TreeInternal>)` as a very basic wrapper, then with tricks like `AsRef` make it super transparent.

Comment: What you might need is `children.iter().cloned().into_iter()`.

Comment: The issue is that the returned iterator borrows the parent node, the iterator itself does not hold a copy of the children. So this function must return something that contains the lifetime of `self`.

Comment: @tadman: I guess you mean `children.clone().into_iter()`: clone the `Vec` itself and return that as an iterator. That way the parent is no longer borrowed and the return value does not need a lifetime. Or you can keep the original borrowing code, and if the user needs not to borrow the parent just do `tree.children().collect()`.

Comment: @rodrigo That might be a better approach, yeah.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Consider reporting it.